# Camera screen for iphone not fitting properly

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etwlm.png)I am working on CustomRenderer for camera on Xamarin forms. The camera screen opens perfectly on Android but it does not fit properly on IOS. I am using Iphone X as a testing device. `liveCameraStream = new UIView () {
                Frame = new CGRect (0f, 0f, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height)
            };`

This is what I am using for setting up the live stream. I have also tried

`liveCameraStream = new UIView () {
                Frame = new CGRect (0f, 0f, 375f, 812f)
            };`

but still it does not work.

Comment: "not fitting properly" is not a very useful description of the problem.  Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @Jason I have added the image as you can see the white part on the top of the image doesnt let the camera to operate. I am not able to get the frame that I have set in shared space as I am able to get that frame on the android camera preview but not on ios.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need native implementation for this. You can follow [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-camera-app3/) which describes the common implementation for the camera.

Comment: I needed many other functionalities that were possible through Native implementation. Is there is anyway to fix the native screen?

Comment: You can still use the common implementation and go for Native where you need it.